# Flash for Ubuntu ARM?

Tags: 12.04, flash, chromium, chromebook, arm

How would I get flash to work on Ubuntu 12.04 on an ARMv7 processor Chromebook? If there is no direct method then would it be possible for me to some how use the Chromebooks built in flash player on Ubuntu?

I have already tried going to adobes site but they do not offer ARM support and I can't find Google chrome for ARM either so I have to use chromium which lacks the flash plugin.

Comment: It seems the only way to get Flash working is to copy over the library from Chrome OS. Search for `libpepflashplayer.so` in this blog post: http://retrofatty.blogspot.in/2013/02/chrubuntu-install-and-fixes.html - and a newer version of the library is linked to in http://www.reddit.com/r/chrubuntu/comments/1att12/installing_flash_for_chromium_browser/c932ycd

Comment: Thank you so much :) I got it to work and will post the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to vt2 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>--></kbd>) then type:

```
cp /opt/google/chrome/pepper/libpepflashplayer.so /home/chronos/[your user # *]/Downloads/
```

Then, in Ubuntu, copy the file to `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins` and type in the terminal:

```
gksudo gedit #(or preferred text editor)
```

Now open `/etc/chromium-browser/default` in that editor and add to this file:

```
CHROMIUM_FLAGS="--ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/plugins/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-version=[Your flash version # **] --ppapi-flash-args=enable_hw_video_decode=0,enable_stagevideo_auto=0,enable_trace_to_console=0"
```

*In Chrome OS, your user number can be found by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>, then clicking the gear in the top right corner, then click the "Workspace" option and then click "Add folder" click open and your user number will be at the top of Chrome in the "Allow/Deny" bar.

**You can find the version by going to `chrome://plugins` in Chrome OS and copy it from the Flash Player. It should look like `14.0.0.177-r1`.

Note: This is not working for chromium 36 but seems to work for other versions of chromium.